# Getting list of folders with Sharefile API

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the Sharefile API to manage files and folders from my project in VB. I need to get all the folders and subfolders from the root on. This is the function that lists the folders contained in the path specified as parameter:

```
Public Function f_FolderList(ByVal path As String) As List(Of String)

            Dim result As New List(Of String)

            Dim requiredParameters As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            requiredParameters.Add("path", path)

            Dim url As String = BuildUrl("folder", "list", requiredParameters)

            Dim jsonObj As JObject = InvokeShareFileOperation(url)
            Dim errorStatus As Boolean = jsonObj.GetValue("error")

            If Not errorStatus Then

                Dim items As JArray = jsonObj.GetValue("value")

                For Each item As JObject In items
                    result.Add(item.GetValue("filename"))
                Next
                Return result
            Else
                'MsgBox("nothing happened")
            End If

            Return result

        End Function
```

And here I try to get all of the folders (for now, just displaying the results in msgboxes):

With this code (now below, after edit), I achieve the folders of level 1 and 2 below the root and I could code lists and sublists forever but that's not doable. I need something that checks the existence of subfolders in order to create sublists as they exist or not.

Can anyone help?

(EDIT)
here are some changes I made, not getting the expected result but closer though (I think).

```
Private Sub btn_FoldersTree_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_FoldersTree.Click

        tv_Folders.Nodes.Clear()

        Dim folderList As List(Of String) = sfs.f_FolderList(rootPath)
        Dim path As String = rootPath
        Dim count As Integer = folderList.Count()
        Dim tempPath As String = String.Empty

        For Each folder As String In folderList

            path += "/" + folder
            MsgBox(path)
            folderList = sfs.f_FolderList(path)

            For Each subfolder In folderList

                tempPath = path
                path += "/" + subfolder
                MsgBox(path)
                folderList = sfs.f_FolderList(path)
                path = tempPath

            Next

            path = rootPath

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: To any potential helper: the first function works fine, returning the name of every folder under the "path" passed as parameter. I'm guessing it's an algorithmic question to recursively call the function through every folder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try playing around with a **recursive function** like this: You start from a `rootPath` like "E:\Program Files\Fiddler2" and anysubfolder will be found and listed in `listDir`

```
Private Sub btn_FoldersTree_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_FoldersTree.Click

    Dim listDir As New List(Of String) '= sfs.f_FolderList(rootPath)
    Dim path As String = rootPath

    GetDirectories(path, listDir)

    'For Each s As String In listDir
        'MsgBox(s)
    'Next
End Sub

Sub GetDirectories(ByVal rootPath As String, ByRef DirectoryList As List(Of String))
    Try
        Dim dirArray() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath)
        DirectoryList.AddRange(dirArray)

        'Get total number of subdirs
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Dir: {0}, SubDirCount: {1}", rootPath, dirArray.Count()))

        For Each Dir As String In dirArray
            GetDirectories(Dir, DirectoryList)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

E.g. **Result**

```
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2, SubDirCount: 6
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\FiddlerHook, SubDirCount: 4
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\FiddlerHook\Content, SubDirCount: 0
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\FiddlerHook\defaults, SubDirCount: 1
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\FiddlerHook\defaults\preferences, SubDirCount: 0
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\FiddlerHook\locale, SubDirCount: 1
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\FiddlerHook\locale\en-US, SubDirCount: 0
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\FiddlerHook\skin, SubDirCount: 0
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\ImportExport, SubDirCount: 0
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\Inspectors, SubDirCount: 0
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\ResponseTemplates, SubDirCount: 0
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\ScriptEditor, SubDirCount: 0
Dir: E:\Program Files\Fiddler2\Scripts, SubDirCount: 0
```

---

**Major EDIT**

Adapted to real sharefile account and structure:

[Video: Sharefile trial account(now deleted) api project built starting from previous link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=DZEZJfEo9AU)

[SharefileExlorer Solution .zip](https://mega.co.nz/#!oNwSBKTT!QT2bLgTbaeRpmoQqVOWGxnedgmsqicWUIDvd_GUQ5JY)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I doesn't work though because I'm accessing Sharefile and the "real" path isn't known to the user. I'm getting Json Objects that represent file or folder names and I can only handle those, adding "/" when needed.

Comment: @chiapa the whole idea is to use a recursive function. If you want more help, provide some sample data in your JSON format and explain the desired result

Comment: you don't need the json format. The json part works and returns the desired result fine. The function is returning file and folder names, as strings, and I'm trying to get all of them, recursively

Comment: I tried it @Vland, doesn't work because of what I said before

Comment: @chiapa If you pass "root" and you get "sub1" and "sub2" as result, do you have to pass "root/sub1" in order to get all sub1 subfolders?

Comment: Yes, I have to pass the whole path, not just the folders' name - you can see that in the code: (path = rootPath + "/" + Str) - then, path is passed again

Comment: @chiapa why are you asking for GetValue("filename")? don't you need a folder name?

Comment: No, filename is the property name of the json object, suits for folders or files. As I said, that part works fine, leave it

Comment: not working: I'm trying to use some of it to see if I can achieve it. By the way, it doesn't work because if a directory has no subdirectories, it jumps off the recursive function

Comment: @chiapa of course, what would you expect? if ask for subdirectories of folder `EmptyFolder` it can't return any.

Comment: I know that. What happens is, imagine the first folder it encounters has no subfolders: it jumps off the recursive function and doesn't go through the rest of the folders. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your effort very much, you really are putting some thought into this and I thank you for that, but I haven't found what I needed yet

Comment: @chiapa This is getting ridiculous. I decided to register a trial account on Sharefile and see for myself if my code is **that** wrong. you can judge yourself [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=DZEZJfEo9AU)

Comment: I just saw your video and it works fine. I can't get it to work, I'm missing something. Filling a treeview with the folders in sharefile is great, could you provide me with the code? Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot. You put a lot of your time into this and I thank you for that. Cheers